# WCF Service referencing third party dlls breaks up on application pool recycle

Tags: wcf, service

This problem has taken our more than 2 weeks but no solution I could manage to find anywhere on web.

Problem statement:

We have created a WCF service which has 3 layers:

1) WCF service layer

2) Facade Layer

3) Agent Layer

Layer 1 uses third party dlls to use the out-of-box contracts and calls facade layer (layer 2) to delegate the request.
Layer 2 simply redirects to the agent layer( layer 3) after business validations or any fore front processing.
Layer 3 uses the same third party dlls (as used in layer 1) to call their APIs to do the business operations.

After deployment everything works perfectly well. As many request comes are served well by the service. Till anyone deliberately or at a fixed point of time on production recycles the application pool hosting this service.

After recycling the service starts behaving weird. The requests are still being processed when I debug the code. At the agent layer (layer 3) same way requests still reach for business operations as expected but then there is some out-of-box business validation error message starts getting thrown from third party dlls. And it continues to throw same error, same behavior, until and unless I clean the temporary ASP.Net folder or re-publish the service code on IIS. This business validation error as such doesn't stop, fault or break our service but then it aborts further processing in layer 3 (agent layer) beyond the point it originates.

I have tried all what I could find searching on web, suggested by many developers but nothing worked. Few (not all) are listed below what I tried:

a.  Cleared cache (both client and server side of third party application) and re-run tests

b.  Created different app pool for wcf service and re-executed tests

c.  Tried on other development environments and local development environment - issue replicates everywhere

d.  Verified by changing publish service level setting and app pool related setting in IIS

e. Cleared AssemblyInfo file of all the settings across all projects in solution.

f. played with different settings at application pool level like one about two overlap flags.

g. gave all kind of permissions at temporary ASP.Net and IIS publish folders level.

Seems some references are getting broken at runtime.

In other services in our solution we have never used contracts from third party dlls but always created a wrapper and they work fine. Third party dlls till now were always used in the agent (layer 3) layer.

I used them in layer 1. Technically I didnt find anything wrong in using them even at layer 1 (service code). May be I am wrong or my design, not sure. But what is happening has taken more than 2 weeks.

technology stack:

```
IIS 7
Visual Studio 2017
MS .Net Framework 4.5.2
```

please suggest.

Comment: what is error you are getting? Please add some details without which it will be hard for anyone to understand the issue.

Comment: I purposely didnt write the error message as it was purely a business specific validation error message which won't give any context around the issue. There is an API from third party application (which we are customizing) which when we call after an app pool refresh starts throwing this business error. Same code, method and API works non-stop and well till this app pool recycle is done.